# Disable access to a folder with a specific name

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Dear StackOverflowers,

I'm looking for a way to disable access to all folders of a specific name, I dynamically make folders with my web app, but some of those folders musn't be accessed by others.

say my app makes folders:
Images
Videos
Scripts

and I want to make all the created folders Scripts be inaccessible? How would I go and make this happen? I'm not that familiar with htaccess, I know its possible to put a htaccess file in every directory, but I want to limit the disk read/writes to make sure the app is fast enough, is there a generic way to do this with 1 htaccess file?

A million thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Apache's `<DirectoryMatch>` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directorymatch), you can easily set this up *at the server level or VirtualHost level*. However, you need access to the core configuration files to do so.

```
<DirectoryMatch "(Images|Videos|Scripts)" >
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

To accomplish the same in a .htaccess file, you'll probably need to make a `RewriteRule` at the top level.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Match directory names and forbid access with the F flag
RewriteRule  .*(Images|Videos|Scripts) - [F]
```

The above should match requests like:

```
http://example.com/stuff/Images/otherstuff
http://example.com/Images1234
http://example.com/dir/dir/dir/Videos/123.mpg
```

Comment: cheers, this worked like a charm!, i did not have access to the original configuration, but managed to do it with .htaccess